# Is the name of `liftM` inspired by lifts in mathematics?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, terminology, category-theory

I'm a math PhD student minoring in CS and currently taking a class in Haskell. We just learned about `liftM`.

The concepts seem similar but I haven't been able to figure out exactly how `liftM` can be thought of as a *lift* in the category-theoretical sense (I know very little category theory and was introduced to lifts in a Topology class).

Comment: [The wikipedia article on Lift in category theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lift_(mathematics)) puts up an exampla by using topology. So i guess they are very related.

Comment: @Redu That argument has a hidden warrant. The obvious follow-up question is: is `liftM` a lift in the category theory sense? (Aphyd asks if `liftM` is a topological lift. You say a category-theoretical lift is a topological lift. But what about that middle step?)

Comment: Ya perhaps it was unclear but my question was whether liftM was a category-theoretical lift.

Comment: Please note that `liftM == fmap` and `liftM2 == liftA2`. So using liftM nowadays makes not much sense, since applicative is a superclass of monad.

Comment: `liftM` is the same as `fmap` and `fmap` is a (Hask) functor's action on morphisms.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is not a practical programming problem. Thus, it's not within the scope of questions appropriate for this site, as defined in [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic) Please also see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Note that it's possible this question might be on-topic in the [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com) or *maybe* even the [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com), though that one's more doubtful.

Answer (score 4):

Given the lack of activity -- and the lack of an obvious connection -- I think it's safe to say that `liftM` was not named because of its connection to topological and category-theoretic lifts.

Instead, I think the term "lift" has come to generically mean any transformation from one domain of reasoning to another, and it is this sense of "lift" that was the historical reason for the name `liftM`. Specifically: `liftM` transforms a pure function, "lift"ing it into the domain of a specific monad.